# Very small camera or endoscope like device with minimal electromagnetic noise generation

Tags: noise, camera

I need to be able to visually monitor movements of a recording electrode inside an electromagnetically shielded chamber. This is a cylindrical chamber of 1" X 1" and is in absolutely dark environment (I can use a light source when the camera is on).

One of the concerns is introduction of noise into the recording electrode by the cameras body (acting as an arial, or by its power source or control circuit). This is why a device like and endoscope with a fiberoptic tube might be better (to put a distance and allow for shielding around the camera).

My question is, is there any camera that best fits this use case? I hope question is clear.

To make it a bit more clear, this is biological signal recording setup, that amplifies and  filters signals in the microvolt range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't you answer your own question? You suggested an endoscope. They are commercial products that can have their own cameras and displays. They would not add electromagnetic interference since they use a fiber optic cable.

Here is an example of one:

[image: endoscope]

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for, I didn't know there are industrial endoscopes you can buy off the shelf!

Comment: Just be aware that, although the scope will not actively add noise to the measurement, it will require a break in the unit's shielding to insert the probe, and this may or may not cause problems.